# Installing Spring Security to enable CSRF protection in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

### What I want

I'm new to the Spring ecosystem and I'm trying to install Spring Security into my existing Spring MVC application to enable CSRF protection.

### What I've done so far:

In my POM I've installed the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I've created a new JAVA class in a custom directory within my application:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebMVCSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      
         
    }
}
```

### My Problem

I have not modified my JSP pages and a CSRF token is not being appended to my forms automatically.  When I submit the forms without a CSRF token (using post), the forms are submitted successfully.

### My Expectation

I was expecting an error due to a lack of CSRF token.

#### Misc:

I'm using Spring framework 5.0.5.RELEASE with Java 8.

My pages are rendered using JSP. My forms are declared as such: `<form id="userForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="${context}/createUser">`

What step am I missing to enable CSRF protection in my Spring MVC application?

Answer (score 0):

try using spring form tag 'form:form'

http://terasolunaorg.github.io/guideline/5.4.1.RELEASE/en/Security/CSRF.html

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, using the form:form tag did not resolve the issue, my forms don't get a CSRF token appended and I can still submit my forms without the token. Either way if CSRF protection was enabled, the expected behavior would be that I can't submit any forms without a CSRF token.   As explained in the question, I can still submit forms with a basic form and no token. That shouldn't be possible when CSRF is enabled correctly.   I'm assuming this is a spring security configuration issue.

Comment: spring-security should enable csrf protection by default, so maybe your config -class isn't recognized at all. is your `@Configurable` active ? is it under your component-scan target ?

and maybe this can be some help -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.1/guides/helloworld-javaconfig.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm using XML to configure my Spring application instead of the java class.  I figured it out, Spring Security wasn't configured properly in the web.xml.  I'll add an answer momentarily.